# Reusing query for duplicate tables

Tags: sql-server

I have Database A & Database B. Both have a User table.

I need to write one stored procedure that will retrieve the data from the correct table depending on a @Parameter passed in.

The idea of the query (data needing returned) in the stored proc needed:

```
SELECT * FROM dbA.User || OR || SELECT * FROM dbB.User
```

I have found the following ways to accomplish this but I want to minimize duplicate code nor add performance slowness/overhead.

Possibilities on my list:

1. Dynamic SQL - harder to maintain, adds overhead in that my
   understanding cannot define execution plans
2. Create a duplicate proc or If/Else inside proc - duplicate code
   never good
3. Table value function - not sure of a way to do this using it as I
   can't use dynamic SQL here or If/Else to tell which query to run.

At this point I am leaning towards Option #2, duplicate code, with the understanding the database setup needs to be better if we want to avoid duplicating code.

I am not saying this is a good database setup, but it is what I am faced with. I have no control over combining database A & B or changing the structure to only have one User table.

Is there any other way to take care of this issue? Or thoughts on my approach?

Comment: IMO the mantra of `duplicate code never good` does not often apply at the database level when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the value of `@Parameter` is `dbA` or `dbB`

```
SELECT * FROM dbA.User where @Parameter = 'dbA'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbB.User where @Parameter = 'dbB'
```

Comment: If I put that in a view (vwUser) say:

`
SELECT *, 'dbA' AS 'Database' FROM dbA.User
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'dbB' AS 'Database' FROM dbB.User
`
Then called: 
SELECT * FROM vwUser WHERE Database = 'dbB'

Would it query through the dbA rows? Is there any guarantee that it wouldn't. 
I played around with this a while back and didn't feel comfortable enough moving forward with this approach as taking a performance hit would be bad.

Comment: @weekendwarrior - that should be an easy test on your side :)  Your original question said the code would live in a stored procedure, so that is the assumption I made with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use option 2 - separate statements / procs.

Referencing a different table is not duplicate code. Inside a database, tables are the "unit of coding." If you're referencing a different table then you're writing new code, not duplicating existing code.

Much like in OO programming. You may have `Foo.DoBuzz()` and `Bar.DoBuzz()`. Just because both types support same-named methods it does not mean you can substitute one for the other. Just because two tables support SELECT (and maybe have same-named columns) it does not mean they can be substituted. There is no equivalent of generics in SQL.